# Format for specifying multiple custom modules in PlayFramework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5, typesafe-config

I have a PlayFramework application where I have multiple custom modules that I would like to load via application.conf. I'm not sure what is the exact syntax for specifying this. I tried:

```
enabled += [com.somemodule, com.othermodule]
```

and

```
enabled += ["com.somemodule","com.othermodule"]
```

but neither works. What is is the format for specifying a list of modules?

Comment: Why not do it in build.sbt (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a line per module:

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.acme.SomeModule"
play.modules.enabled += "com.acme.OtherModule"
```

[HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md) has a syntax to [append an array to another](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#the--field-separator), but I would not recommend it:

```
play.modules.enabled = ${?play.modules.enabled} [ "com.acme.SomeModule", "com.acme.OtherModule" ]
```

Comment: Essentially both options are the same. It's a matter of taste.